# XGBoostError : value for parameter exceed bound

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I am training a XGBoost model and doing hyper-parameter tuning using randomizedSearchCV. I specify the parameter distribution as:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

# Define a xgboost regression model
model = XGBRegressor()

params = {
      "colsample_bytree": uniform(0.1, 0.2), # fraction of cols to sample
      "gamma": uniform(0, 0.3), # min loss reduction required for next split
      "learning_rate": uniform(0.02, 0.3), # default 0.1 
      "n_estimators": randint(100, 150), # default 100
      "subsample": uniform(0.8, 0.75) # % of rows to use in training sample
}

r = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions=params, n_iter=100, 
scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", cv=3, n_jobs=1)
```

I get the following error when even though the range I have specified for `subsample` is lower the bound [0,1].

```
raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
   xgboost.core.XGBoostError: value 1.10671 for Parameter subsample exceed bound [0,1]

  warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue comes from:

```
uniform(0.8, 0.75)
```

For numpy and random the first value of the function defines the lower limit and the second value the upper limit. Hence, for numpy and random you want:

```
uniform(0.75, 0.8)
```

This applies for numpy.random.uniform and random.uniform:

- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

However, for scipy.stats.uniform the definition is slightly different. Which is "Using the parameters loc and scale, one obtains the uniform distribution on [loc, loc + scale]." So for scipy you want:

```
uniform(0.75, 0.05)
```

Comment: I fixed the params, `"colsample_bytree": uniform(0.5, 1)`, however, I am still running into the error. `raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: value 1.0913 for Parameter colsample_bytree exceed bound [0,1]`

Comment: From where do you import the uniform function? I just saw that there also exists a scipy function. That is then defined different.

Comment: from scipy.stats import uniform

Comment: I think for scipy.stats you should use uniform(0.5, 0.5).

Comment: So for scipy uniform. argument a + argument b  should not be greater than 1 for colsample_bytree. See the adjusted answer above.